# How to prove that given a binary operator $*$, $a * b = a^2 - ab + b^2$ is associative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, binary-operations

No matter how hard I try I cannot seem to prove that, given the binary operator $*$, the operation $a * b = a^2 - ab + b^2$ is associative.
This is what I have tried:

$(a * b) * c = a * (b * c) [Associativity];

$(a^2 - ab + b^2) * c = a * (b^2 - bc + c^2)$;

I have tried using $(a - b)^2$: $(a - b)^2 * c = a * (b - c)^2$;

Like other associativity problems, I could prove that but reaching an equality after expanding both sides, but that doesn't seems to be the case here. What am I doing wrong? Is this even an associative operation?

Comment: You can't use $(a-b)^2$ here. $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$, but here, the coefficient of $ab$ is $-1$, not $-2$.

Comment: This is not associative

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $\, $ Let $\,d(f(a))\,$ be the  degree of $\,a\,$ in the polynomial $f(a)$.

Then $\,d(a*b) = 2\, $ so $\,d((a*b)*c) = 4\,$ but $\,d(a*(b*c)) = 2\,$ by $\,d(b*c) = 0\,$

Answer (score 3):

$$1 * (2 * 3)=1 * (2^2-2*3+3^2)=1 * 7=1^2-1*7+7^2=43$$
$$(1 * 2) * 3=(1^2-1*2+2^2) * 3=3 * 3=3^2-3*3+3^2=9$$
Therefore, $*$ is not associative. Always remember to guess and check values of $a,b,c$ to see if an operation is associative before trying to prove it!

---

Now, to show you why this is not associative, let's expand this out. In the following equations, the quantities are not actually equal, but we are going to show this by expanding each side out separately.

As you said, we have:
$$(a^2-ab+b^2) * c=a * (b^2-bc+c^2)$$
Substitute into the formula:
$$(a^2-ab+b^2)^2-c(a^2-ab+b^2)+c^2=a^2-a(b^2-bc+c^2)+(b^2-bc+c^2)^2$$
Distribute the $-c$ on the left side and the $-a$ on the right sode:
$$(a^2-ab+b^2)^2-ca^2+abc-cb^2+c^2=a^2-ab^2+abc-ac^2+(b^2-bc+c^2)^2$$
Use the $(u+v+w)^2=u^2+v^2+w^2+2uv+2uw+2vw$ identity to square the trionmials:
$$a^4+a^2b^2+b^4-2a^3b+2a^2b^2-2ab^3-ca^2+abc-cb^2+c^2 \\ =a^2-ab^2+abc-ac^2+b^4+b^2c^2+c^4-2b^3c+2b^2c^2-2bc^3$$
Add like terms and rearrange terms:
$$abc+a^4-2a^3b+3a^2b^2-2ab^3+b^4-ca^2-cb^2+c^2 \\ =abc+b^4-2b^3c+3b^2c^2-2bc^3+c^4-ab^2-ac^2+a^2$$
Hopefully, you see now that wherever there is $a$ on the left side, there is $b$ on the right side, wherever there is $b$ on the left side, there is $c$ on the right side, and wherever there is $a$ on the right side. Therefore, the right side is the left side with those substitutions, or $(b * c) * a$. However, originally, the right side was $a* (b * c)$, so:
$$a * (b * c)=(b * c) * a$$
However, this just shows commutativity, not associativity, so this operation isn't associative since the left and right side in the above equations aren't the same.

Answer (score 1):

No. $(a,b,c) = (4,2,1).$

$$4 * 2 = 16 - 8 + 4 = 12.$$
$$ 12 * 1 = 144 - 12 + 1 = 133 $$
$$ 2 * 1 = 4 - 2 + 1 = 3 $$
$$ 4 * 3 = 16 - 12 + 9 = 13 $$

Answer (score 1):

Just do it:

$(a*b)*c = (a^2 - ab + b^2)*c = (a^2 - ab + b^2)^2-a^2c +abc-b^2c+c^2=a^4 -2a^3b + 3a^2b^2 -2ab^3+b^4-a^2c+abc-b^2c+c^2$

$a*(b*c) = a^2-a (b^2-bc+c^2) +(b^2 - bc + c^2)^2$

It's pretty clear these need not be equal.  One is "dominated" by $a^4$ and $b^4$ while the other is dominated by $c^4$ and $b^4$.

Let $a=100$, $b=c=0$.  Then $(a*b)*c = (a*0)^2 -(a*0)0+0^2=(a*0)^2=(100^2-0*100+0)^2=100^4$.  Whereas $a*(b*c)=100^2 -100 (0*0)+(0*)^2=100^2-100 (0^2-0*0+0^2)+(0^2-0*0+0^2)^2=100^2$

Comment: The algebra of this operation is much more complicated than this. You do not just do $b * c$ out and then multiply by $a$. You have to substitute the expression for $b * c$ into the formula for $u * v$, meaning that one has to square a trinomial. This is why the questioner had hesitation against doing it out.

Comment: Hmm, what the heck was I thinking?